# How To Connect To Remote Server IP Using MSSQL2005?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2005, web-config

I have a following details provided by our mssql2005 database provider

```
Server IP : 100.20.255.34
Databaase name : insss
User: nas0
password : ymkv45SEv
```

i have the following connectionstring in my web.config file in my offline site as :

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

**I want**

how to edit my web.config connection string mentioned above using the details provided above so that it connect to my MSSQl2005 hosting provider .... ?

I don't know how to edit connection string to do that !!

**When i run my site [www.vbi.volvobusesindia.com](http://www.vbi.volvobusesindia.com) then the following error occurs in top of the page ...**

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: I hope those aren't your real database login credentials, Clix.

Comment: please don't use caps lock, it's very annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work just fine:

```
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=100.20.255.34;Initial Catalog=insss;User ID=nas0;Password=ymkv45SEv;Integrated Security=False" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: when i run my site it shows the following error in top of the page ..

www.vbi.volvobusesindia.com

Comment: This means that for some reason the MSSQL server is not accessible from the network where your web server resides  - this could be a Firewall issue (in this case they will need to allow connecting to MSSQL from your external IP address) or maybe they assigned a custom port to connect to MSSQL and you just need to specify it in the connection string as well.